# Building a linked list in c#

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, iteration, complexity-theory

I am currently writing an algorithm to build a chain of objects in c#.  The ordering of the object is important as they represent a sequence of events in a specific order.  Object A performs an action and contains a reference to Object B which performs and action and so on.  The problem I have is that the initial state of the objects is orderless.  I have dictionary containing each object and the name of the next object in the series.  What I am struggling with is devising a fast algorithm to "sort" them.  My initial assumption is to iterate through the dictionary and for each value, look for a key which matches it and add both of these objects to another list.  There are a few problems:
1. Determining the first object in the chain.
2. Very high complexity in using nested loops.
3. Deciding on what c# objects to use to house the chain of objects.

I was hoping someone has experience with a sorting algorithm to accomplish this or has done something similar.  All comments and help are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you post code? I'm having trouble visualizing/imagining the approach you're describing.

Comment: use Dictionary key as the value you need to get sorted [I think it's a property which is unique] . Sort the key set and get it to a list. Then use LinkedList to add objects from Dictionary

Comment: I don't have any code worth sharing as I'm struggling to conceptualize the problem myself.   At a high level I have a list of sql jobs we run daily in a chain.  In the list is all of the jobs and the job it kicks off.  I am attempting to build a web page to view this job chain visually.  My first problem is to build the aforementioned job chain in c#.  I was hoping for some advice on how to accomplish this.

Comment: How do you know what job a job kicks off?  Manual analysis, or do you have some code reading that dynamically, if so, post that.

Comment: I am querying our sql servers for all jobs (sysjobs, sysjobsteps) and building a list of all jobs and the step which kicks off another jobs.  One point of complexity is that there are mutliple job chains that can be built from the list.  Single jobs exist as well as multiple, multi job chains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last comment to your post is important-- the fact that there are multiple job chains.  It's not a sorting exercise; it's a graph-building exercise.

You already have a hash containing each object and its successor(s).  I'm assuming an object can have multiple successors, and likewise can have multiple predecessors (just to be sufficiently general).  Build another hash with each object and its predecessor(s), and from the two you can easily show any chart or tree of relationships you want.

Build the Predecessors hash by iterating through the Successors hash.  For each Successors key A with a successor B, insert a Predecessors key B showing a predecessor A.  O(n).

With these two hashes, you can write functions to recursively construct either a complete tree of parents (predecessors) or children (successors) for any given object.

EDIT: Note that if you want to know which jobs are original (have no predecessors) or terminal (have no successors), for purposes of building a complete display, you would have to keep track of those separately, with, say, two arrays named Originals and Terminals.  You can build Terminals as you iterate through your original Successors hash in order to build Predecessors, and build Originals with one final pass through Predecessors, finding entries that have no predecessor.  But if you just want to be able to satisfy specific queries about individual objects, Successors and Predecessors should do it.